# Scalish way to read file and do something when end of file reached

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

I'm trying to find a more elegant and scalaish way to read a file line by line and call a function
when the end of file is reached. Here is my current implementation :

```
val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile("data.txt")    
for(line  <- source.getLines())
{
   // do something with data
   println(line)
}

// end of file reached do something else
doSomethingWithAllDataLoaded()
```

Here, What I need something less iterative and run this file reading concurrently and finally call the callback function each end of file is reached.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file a bit more Scala-style like this:

```
val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile("data.txt")
source.getLines.foreach(println(_))
```

To process lines in parallel consider [parallel collections](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html). This would look like this:

```
source.getLines.toList.par.foreach(println(_))
```

But keep in mind that this way you first read all lines from the file, and then start processing them in parallel.

Hope this helps

**EDIT**:

If you want to avoid loading files in memory - just use `Source.fromFile(...).getLines`. It returns an `Iterator[String]` which is already lazy. Even more, you **should not** use `.toList` or similar to avoid memory issues. Methods like this destroy all the laziness of an `Iterator` and force strict (non-lazy, eager) collections.

Comment: In fact, what I want to do is to read many files in parallel and avoid to load them in memory since they are large.

Comment: Parallel disk IO ? Usually a bad idea. Disks access is sequential, reading several file at the same time will imply moving the magnetic heads back and forth which slows down everything... Better to read sequentially chunks of data and parallelize chunk processing. Of course you could also consider an (expensive) fancy parallel IO filesystem...

Comment: @paradigmatic what about SSD drives? no disks, no heads.. random access time should be fast.

Comment: @cyrillk Indeed lower latency means lower slow-down. But I don't think that you can read several files in parallel and obtain a speed-up in contrast to reading the same files on the same disk sequentially.